# React Report did not match any routes warning @ bundle.js:11780

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am learning React-router now and the file report did not match any router

My router wrote like this

This is my router.js

```
import '../../node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { browserHistory, Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

// import Init from '../main'
import SideBar from '../components/SideBar'
import App from '../components/App'
import Home from '../components/Home'
import About from '../components/About'
import Features from '../components/Features'


ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
    <SideBar/>

    <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path='/' component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Home} />
                <Route path='about' component={About} />
                <Route path='features' component={Features} />
            </Route>
    </Router>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

It should render `SideBar` and `Home` Components in the browser but can only find the `SideBar` Component.

[image]

Comment: **<SideBar/>** should be inside your App component which is the main entry point.  You should return only the Router component

Answer (score 0):

Add "/about"  in route path 
Where 
The code looks like

And use 
Localhost: your port number /project folder/about

I think this will work for you